# In einer Beschwerde: "Damit geht's doch schon mal los"

Tags: meaning

I​ch lese jetzt *Herr Lehmann​* von Sven Regener​. Kann jemand mir bitte den folgenden fett ​gedruckten Satz, insbesondere die Bedeutung dieses ​besonderen ​Gebrauchs von ​"​losgehen​"​, erklären?​ Herr Lehmann bekl​agt sich hier darüber​​, dass seine Mutter ih​n​ sehr früh anruft​ und es lange Zeit klingeln lässt, ohne aufzulegen​, während er noch versucht zu schlafen.

> Genauer gesagt, dachte Herr Lehmann, hätte ich es vor allem nicht
> dreßigmal klingeln lassen, **damit geht’s doch schon mal los**, dachte er. Fünfmal, das ist okay, zumal die meisten Leute Anrufbeantworter haben, die nicht ohne Grund schon nach vier- oder fünfmaligem Klingeln anspringen, dachte Herr Lehmann und bedauerte, daß er sich noch immer nicht ein solches Gerät angeschafft hatte...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [ich hätte] es vor allem nicht 30 mal klingeln lassen, *damit geht’s doch schon mal los*

"Losgehen" bedeutet, anfangen zu gehen. "Damit geht es los" bedeutet somit "That is what it starts with". Etwas sperrig und niemand würde das im Englischen sagen. Aber es gibt etwas sehr, sehr ähnliches:

> I would not have let it ring 30 times *to begin with*.

or

> I would not have let it ring 30 times *for starters*.

Comment: Bedeutet "I rang 30 times." wirklich, "Ich habe es 30 mal klingeln lassen."? Da "to ring somebody" (auch?) "jemanden anrufen" bedeutet, ist das vermutlich mindestens mehrdeutig - der deutsche Satz sagt ja eben _nicht_ aus, dass 30 mal angerufen wurde, sondern dass genau einmal angerufen wurde, dabei aber 30 Freizeichen (bzw. die Zeitspanne, die notwendig war, damit das Telefon beim Angerufenen 30 mal klingelte) abgewartet wurden.

Comment: hm, gute Frage, wenn du da was besseres weisst übernehme ich es gerne.

Comment: Danke! Auf English: I wouldn't have let it ring 30 times. Genauso wie auf Deutsch.

Answer (score 1):

»Losgehen« hat hier keine extravagante Bedeutung, bedeutet »anfangen«. Extravagant dagegen ist, dass das Losgehen mit dem Klingeln in Verbindung gebracht wird.

Die Reihenfolge ist ja die:

- Die Mutter ruft zu einer frühen Uhrzeit an
- Die Mutter lässt es lange klingeln

Die Klage müsste daher eher wie folgt lauten:

> Überhaupt so früh anzurufen, damit geht's doch schon mal los! Und es
> dann auch noch 30 Mal klingeln lassen!

Mag sein, dass der Kontext diese Irritation auflöst. Kann ich nicht sagen.

Die Sätze

> - Damit geht's doch schon mal los
> - Damit fängt's doch schon mal an

bedeuten so viel wie:

> Das ist das Erste, was ich zum Vorwurf mache / zu beanstanden habe

Answer (score 0):

Ich gehe davon aus, dass du mit

> damit geht's los

keinerlei Probleme hast - das würde man mit "that's where it starts" übersetzen. Die Frage könnte sein, was "es" ist, das losgeht - Und das ist hauptsächlich seine eigene Empörung. Es ist davon auszugehen, dass er sich noch über mehr als das 30-malige Klingelnlassen aufregt (denn, wenn's damit "losgeht", kommt sicher noch mehr).

> doch

und

> schon

tragen eigentlich zur Kernaussage des Satzes nicht viel bei - beides sind Partikel, die zur "Dekoration" und zum Setzen von Betonungen verwendet werden.

*Doch* drückt in Ausrufesätzen Empörung oder Entrüstung aus.

*Schon* verstärkt eine Aussage oder Feststellung und drückt emotionale Beteiligung aus.

Wir haben es also mit einem Sprecher zu tun, der empört darüber  ist, dass der Anrufer ihn mit anhaltendem Klingelnlassen des Telefons geweckt hat. Nachdem er meinte, dass es damit "losgeht", wird er sich auch noch über mehr als nur das Klingeln des Telefons empören.

Comment: Danke, ich habe noch ein bisschen weiteren Kontext hinzugefügt, da ich sehe, dass du und @nvoigt euch nicht komplett einig seid, um was es geht. Wenn ich recht verstehe, glaubt nvoigt, dass Herr Lehman selbst nicht so etwas wie dreißigmal Klingeln lassen machen würde, mit diesem Beherrschung seitens Lehmanns geht's los. Aber nach deiner Antwort geht's los mit Herr Lehmann's Empörung.